# Pandas - Calculate lookback period based on threshold condition

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following inefficient loop that I'd like to clean up.  We lookback over the data while a condition is true and count the number of times a threshold condition is met.

Input variables are **x** and **a**, the desired/correct output is **countA**.

| x | a | countA |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1.00 | 0 | 0 |
| 1.00 | 4 | 0 |
| 0.75 | 8 | 1 |
| 1.00 | 0 | 1 |
| 0.75 | 1 | 1 |
| 0.75 | 9 | 2 |
| 0.75 | 4 | 2 |
| 0.50 | 1 | 1 |
| 0.75 | 0 | 2 |
| 0.75 | 0 | 2 |
| 1.00 | 2 | 0 |
| 0.75 | 3 | 2 |
| 0.75 | 0 | 2 |
| 1.00 | 0 | 0 |
| 0.75 | 1 | 2 |
| 0.75 | 6 | 3 |
| 0.50 | 5 | 2 |

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.read_csv('input.csv')

lb = 0.25
thres = 5
df['countA'] = np.nan

for i in reversed(df.index):
    j = 0
    countA = 0
    
    while abs(df['x'][i] - df['x'][i - j]) <= lb:
        if i <= j:
            break
        if df['a'][i - j] >= thres:
            countA+=1
        j+=1

    df['countA'][i] = countA
```

Comment: what is the desired output?

Comment: Can you create a new column that shows lagged variables and select based on that?

Comment: The desired output is "countA", the input variables are only 'x' and 'a'.